# How to create a suggester in azure search index

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

When I try to create a suggester on an index using .net sdk I get an error.

I can create index successfully using .net SDK but when I try to add suggester I get an error.

My index code:

```
var index = new Index()
{
Name = "customeridex",
Fields = FieldBuilder.BuildForType<AutocompleteResponseDetail>(),
Suggesters = new List<Suggester>() {new Suggester()
{
Name="cg",
SourceFields= new string[] { "Title", "Description" }
}}
};
```

The error message I get:
'The request is invalid. Details: definition: One or more fields in suggester 'cg' are not defined as a field in the index. Fields: Title, Description.'

Although I have fields: Title and description in my index

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to include the declaration of AutocompleteResponseDetail?

Comment: My bad, it was casing error. Above sourcefields need to be all small to match index schema

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 var definition = new Index()
            {
                Name = "customeridex",
                Fields = FieldBuilder.BuildForType<AutocompleteResponseDetail>(),
                Suggesters = new List<Suggester> {new Suggester("cg","Title", "Description") }
            };
```

I have tested on my side and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, it was casing error. Above sourcefields need to be all small to match index schema.